# Trying to load my Angular scripts dynamically yields an "angular not found" error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My Angular app is working fine. However, I got tired of having so many `script` tags in my HTML, so I wrote a little script to -- I thought -- generate all the tags for me:

```
var scriptURLs = [
  "js/angular.min.js",
  "js/firebase.min.js",
  "js/angularfire.min.js",
  "js/myapp.js",
  "js/mycontroller.js"
  // ...and so on
]
window.onload = function loadScripts(){
  scriptURLs.forEach(function(url){
    var el = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    el.src = url;
    document.head.appendChild(el);
  });
}
```

This does generate all the `script` tags, and the URLs are all correct: no 404s are being thrown. However, this yields a series of `angular is not defined` errors. I've tried it without `window.onload` as well with the same result.

It's no problem to hardcode all the `script` tags in my HTML again, or I can use Grunt or some other dependency manager, but I'd still like to know why this is occurring.

The order of the files throwing the errors is slightly different every time I reload the page, so it looks like the files are being loaded asynchronously and thus executed in the wrong order. But my understanding of `script` tags is that they're blocking and loaded and executed synchronously (unless you use the `async` attribute, which I'm not). So I'm a little confused!

Any thoughts as to why this is happening? Thank you!

Comment: better to use a script loading manager like require.js , or use an automation tool like grunt or gulp to add all the tags for you

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, but I'd still like to understand why this is occurring.

Comment: note that you already have `".js"` in the url's shown and are concatenating it again

Comment: also doing this approach should also probably manually bootstrap angular rather than use ng-app

Comment: My gut tells me it's something to do within the part of the lifecycle of the page you're in when you're trying to load the scripts. Notice that this script takes place in `window.onload`, which is after the entire DOM has already loaded. I wonder if that could be causing an issue.

Comment: You also might be running into a race condition between the time Angular takes to bootstrap itself and the load of the additional scripts that require Angular. As another commenter suggested, you might want to manually bootstrap Angular.

Comment: @JoshBeam It's an identical result with and without `window.onload`. I'll look into manual bootstrapping. Thanks.

Comment: see what happens if you use document.write instead of waiting for onload and appending script tags

Answer (score 2):

Removing the `ng-app` directive, removing `window.onload`, and manually bootstrapping my app fixed it:

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularFire/1.1.3/angularfire.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

JS:

```
loadScripts();
angular.element(document.head).ready(function(){
  angular.bootstrap(document, ["messageBoard"]);
});
```